# pylatex Command

Tags: macros, pylatex

I'm using pylatex and I need to attach a logo in the header.

I want to use this latex example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(-500,0){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}} \end{picture}}
\begin{document}
SOMETHING
\end{document}
```

I tried with this:

```
import pylatex as pyl
    pyl.Command('rhead',
            arguments=NoEscape(r'\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}} \end{picture}')).dumps()
```

But is does not work. I do not get an error, it simly does not include it in the tex file. Thank you

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dumps()` function is useful for debugging, because it allows you to see generated commands in the Python console. However, to include commands in the LaTeX document you should use `.append` with the command itself as argument (and not the dump).

MWE:

```py
import pylatex as pyl

doc = pyl.Document()
doc.packages.append(pyl.Package('graphicx'))
doc.packages.append(pyl.Package('fancyhdr'))

doc.preamble.append(pyl.Command('pagestyle', 'fancy'))
doc.preamble.append(pyl.Command('rhead',arguments=pyl.NoEscape(r'\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}} \end{picture}')))

doc.append('abc')

doc.generate_pdf('rheadtest', clean_tex=False)
```

Result (`.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\rhead{\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}} \end{picture}}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
abc%
\end{document}
```

Result (`.pdf`):

[image]

Comment: doc.preamble!!! I've been looking for something like this for long. Thank you!